# Shell command to monitor changes in a file

Tags: linux, shell

I know there was a command on Unix that I could use to monitor a file and see changes that are getting written to it. This was quite useful especially for checking log files.

Do you know what it is called?

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Do you mean

```
tail -f logfile.log
```

?

([Man page for tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html))

Comment: Thanks I think that's the one I was looking for. But does it update in realtime? Can I somehow change the interval if it does not?

Comment: Yes, it's real time.

Comment: Sidenote: If your distribution provides the tailf command, use that in preference to tail -f. tailf is more efficient because it doesn't need to access the watched file if it's not being written to (poll accesses are annoying if you mounted the file system with atime updating.)

Comment: At [super user I found an answer](http://superuser.com/a/155214) recommending _tail -F_ instead of _-f_ , too

Comment: `tail -F` will follow filenames rather than file objects, which is especially useful in case of log file rotation.

Comment: works like charm!

Comment: Update, a few years later: `tailf` is now deprecated and `tail -f` is safe. (confirm this on your system with `man tailf`.) See documentation: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tailf.1.html

Answer (score 151):

You probably meant tail, as per Jon Skeet's answer.

Another useful one is [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch); it allows you to run a command periodically and see the output full screen. For example:

```
watch -n 10 -d ls -l /var/adm/messages
```

Will run the command `ls -l /var/adm/messages` every 10 seconds, and highlight the difference in the output between subsequent runs. (Useful for watching how quickly a logfile is growing, for example).

Answer (score 79):

`inotifywait` from [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) is useful if you want to run a command every time a file (or any files in a directory) change. For example:

```
inotifywait -r -m -e modify /var/log | 
   while read file_path file_event file_name; do 
       echo ${file_path}${file_name} event: ${file_event}
   done
```

output:

```
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
/var/log/messages event: MODIFY
/var/log/kern event: MODIFY
...
```

Comment: Just a note that `path` isn't the greatest choice for a variable name. On `zsh`, it seems that environment vars aren't case-sensitive. For me, setting `path` causes `PATH` to also get set, and that basically means nothing will execute until you fix that.
On `bash`, setting `path` has no effect on `PATH`.

Comment: @Thanatos Zsh variables *are* case-sensitive, but among the variables set by Zsh itself, Zsh "ties" the `*PATH` variables to an **array** of the same name, but **lowercase**. Tied variables always consist of a scalar and an array (e.g. `PATH` and `path`), and modifying one modifies the other. A key feature is that the array version is automatically split on the separator in the scalar version (the `:`). See for yourself with `print "$PATH\n$path"`. The second paragraph in the `PARAMETERS USED BY THE SHELL` section in the `zshparam(1)` man page has more detailed information.

Comment: As a further note, there's quite a few variables used by Zsh that are tied, not just `PATH` and `path`. They are all listed in the section in my previous comment including, but not limited to: `FPATH`/`fpath`, `CDPATH`/`cdpath`, `MANPATH`/`manpath`, `FIGNORE`/`fignore`, and more.

Answer (score 41):

I prefer using `less +FG`<sup>1</sup> over `tail -f` because I find myself needing to search a log file for a specific error or ID.  If I need to search for something, I type `^C` to stop following the file and `?` to start searching backwards.

Key bindings are pretty much the same as in `vi`.  Any command can be initialized on startup using the `+` option:

```
+cmd   Causes  the  specified  cmd  to be executed each time a new file is
       examined.  For example, +G causes less to  initially  display  each
       file starting at the end rather than the beginning.
```

For really long logs, I find it convenient to use the `-n` option which turns off line numbering.  From the manpage:

```
-n or --line-numbers
          Suppresses line numbers.  The default (to use line numbers)  may
          cause  less  to run more slowly in some cases, especially with a
          very large input file.  Suppressing line  numbers  with  the  -n
          option  will  avoid this problem.  Using line numbers means: the
          line number will be displayed in the verbose prompt and in the =
          command,  and the v command will pass the current line number to
          the editor (see also  the  discussion  of  LESSEDIT  in  PROMPTS
          below).
```

---

<sub>1. Hat-tip to [rgmarcha](https://serverfault.com/users/4815/rgmarcha) for pointing this out in the comments.</sub>

Comment: Remember to set an `alias` with your desired options, so you don't have to type them out every single time.

Comment: Actually, you should generally prefer shell functions over aliases in most cases.

Comment: I would like to know why `+FG` instead of `+F`?

Answer (score 22):

`tail` is great ... `less` can also be used  start less on the file i.e. `less myfile` then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.  This has `less` act as `tail`.

Comment: less +F myfile  will make it too

Answer (score 20):

I'm editing a LaTeX file and wanted to monitor it also for changes somewhere in the middle.  I whipped up the following little shell script that proved useful to me.  I hope it'll also come in handy to someone else.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
CMD="$2"
LAST=`ls -l "$FILE"`
while true; do
  sleep 1
  NEW=`ls -l "$FILE"`
  if [ "$NEW" != "$LAST" ]; then
    "$CMD" "$FILE"
    LAST="$NEW"
  fi
done
```

Save it as `watch.sh` and do `chmod u+x watch.sh`. Then I execute it as follows:

`./watch.sh file.tex pdflatex`

If you want the command only to be run if actual modification takes place, you can use `` `md5sum "$FILE"` `` instead of `` `ls -l "$FILE"` ``.

Comment: to watch directories and their contents instead of a single file: `NEW=\`tree -sDct . -I 'ignore_pattern|another_pattern'\``

Answer (score 8):

you can use the [tailf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tailf)  command its very easiest one

```
tailf logfile.log
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use inotifywatch/inotifywait which hook into the kernels inotify subsystem. This way you can also watch for things like "open", "close" or "access".

But if you're simply want to get appended lines to stdout i agree on tail.

Answer (score 3):

Tail is the standard, traditional, available everywhere unix tool. A little more sophisticated tool is [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) which can monitor several files simultaneously and does syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

If I want to be able to search around the file in addition to just tailing it, I use less with the "F" command.

When using tail, keep in mind that additional arguments are needed if the file might be rolling over or replaced by edit (default mode for vim's :w).

`tail -f <filename>` will cause tail to store the file descriptor and follow it. If the file is replaced the descriptor will be changed. The benefit of following the file descriptor is that if the file is renamed, you will still be following it.

`tail --follow=<filename>` will make tail track the named file by reopening it periodically to see if it has been replaced.

`--retry` is another useful option if you want to tail a log file but the file hasn't been created yet.

`tail -F <filename>` is a shortcut for `--follow=<filename> --retry`.

Answer (score 3):

Forget tailf, diff is the command you want.
Here is a good trick to watch the differences as they happen in real time (or close) between 2 files or in one file being written to.

You can use these methods to modify the behavior whatever way you want, such as writing the changes to a file to keep record. Play around with the interval of watch or other options for the commands below.

You have 1 file and you want to watch as changes are made to it:

So heres what to do:

1. copy the file

   ```
   cp file file2
   ```
2. write a bash script to find the differences, and update file2

   ```
   touch check-differences.sh
   nano check-differences.sh
   chmod 755 check-differences.sh
   ```
3. Here's a basic idea for the script. Make it write to a file if you want

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   diff file file2
   cp file file2
   ```
4. Next you can either watch the differences on screen using watch

   ```
   watch ./check-differences
   ```

this will update every 2 seconds by default. So if you need to go back and read them, then write the output of diff to a file in the script.

Or use `cron` to run your script regularly if you don't need to see output.

Answer (score 1):

While `tail -f somefile.txt` keeps scrolling with new data, I *sometimes* prefer `less +G somefile.txt` as well to look at a patch of latest data in the file.

Comment: I think that is all covered in [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/1901/214507) from 7 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I used this, to execute some function on file change:

```
sudo apt-get install inotify-hookable
inotify-hookable -w ./my_dir_to_monitor  -c "mkdir blabla"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### tail

The most basic version just uses `tail` but has the downside of adding all output directly to your terminal:

```
tail -f path/to/log_file.log
```

#### watch + tail (my pick)

I like the following instead so the output doesn't exceed the amount of lines (N) I want to see displayed at once:

```
watch -n 2 tail -n N path/to/log_file.log
```

It is better, to me, than using `less` as it also shows you the command and some more info at the top.

#### less

However, `less` is simpler and does let you scroll through the output and automatically fits the number of lines to the size of your screen:

```
less +F path/to/log_file.log
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76541893/8285811) for a version of this that handles carriage returns.